# JavaScript for loop is not working

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why this loop is not working when I put the start value of 2 in but it works when I do 1 or 10?

```
var button = document.getElementById('generate');
var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');
var start;
var end;

button.onclick = function(){
    resultsDiv.innerHTML = "";

    start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    end = document.getElementById('end').value;     

    generateTags(start,end);

};

function generateTags(start, stop){
    for(i=start; i<=stop; i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the html code

Comment: Please edit your post to make the title more descriptive. Hundreds or thousands of posts are created because *Javascript for loop not working*, and seeing those thousands of posts with the same title in a list of search results is useless to future users of the site. When you make that [edit], you can also be more clear about the problem than *is not working*. How **specifically** is it *not working*? What do you expect it to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: what is the value of start and stop and kindly share your html code alos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `document.getElementById("something").value` returns a `string`.

So you are taking the values as `string`. While comparing the `2` and `10` as strings `10` is less than `2` lexicographically. So it doesn't work. For more info, [see this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

```js
function generate()
{
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var stop = document.getElementById("stop").value;
    console.log(typeof start, typeof stop);
    
    start = parseInt(start);
    stop = parseInt(stop);
    
    console.log(typeof start, typeof stop);
    for(var i=start;i<=stop;i++)
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="start">
<input id="stop">
<button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
```

In the above example, I have converted the string to numbers using `parseInt` and proceeded further. You can remove the `typeof` consoles. I just added them to show the types of values.

Comment: Oh my god, you are a lifesaver! That was driving me insane.